# Unknown option LegendPosition (even after Needs["PlotLegends`"]) (Mathematica 10.0)

Tags: plotting, legending, warning-messages

I'm running Mathematica 10.0 for Students. When I tried

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
B[Q_, K_] := Cos[\[Pi]/(Floor[Q/K] + 2)];
q = 3;
(* Plot B[q,k] for various k plus 2 horizontal lines *)
Plot[{B[q, k], 0.75, 0.90}, {k, 1, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Style["B(q,k)", FontFamily -> "Times", Italic, 18], 
   Style["0.75", FontFamily -> "Times", 18], 
   Style["0.90", FontFamily -> "Times", 18]}, 
 LegendPosition -> {0, 0}]
```

I always got the error

```
Plot::optx: "Unknown option LegendPosition->{0,0} in ...
```

Googling and reading the help file didn't help me. Could you please tell me how to fix this? (Deleting `LegendPosition` solves the problem but I'd rather be able to use the option). Thank you very much.

**Edit**: Without LegendPosition, the output looks like this

[image]

I would like to have the legend box go on the empty space on the right side but below the orange line (i.e. the legend box is on top of the figure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is `PlotLegend` instead of `PlotLegends`
(This is on Windows 7 in Mathematica 10.0.2 X64)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using *Mathematica* 10.  Generally speaking you should abandon the old PlotLegends package and use the newer, better legending functions.  For your example:

```
B[Q_, K_] := Cos[π/(⌊Q/K⌋ + 2)];
q = 3;

Plot[{B[q, k], 0.75, 0.90}, {k, 1, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend["Expressions", 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", Italic, 18},
    LegendFunction -> "Panel"
  ] ~Placed~ {0.7, 0.45}
]
```

[image]